# Failure in VBA code with HLookup function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, lookup-tables

My script below includes a VBA HLookup function at the end of the code.The way it is currently, supplies an incorrect result. My goal is to find the largest figure in the table (occData) and then to find the value in the top row which is related to the largest number found in the table.

In fact, the HLookup function in its current state comes up with the value contained in the last cell of the first row (ResultVector).

Also I made use of the respective Excel function to doublecheck VBA [ " =HLOOKUP(AV2;K1:AS2;1) "]. This  method generates the incorrect result identical with the VBA code.

Can't figure out where did I commit a mistake.

( irrelevant sections of the code have been cleared )

```
Sub freq()

Worksheets("feldolg").Activate
Dim tart As Range
    Set tart = Range("B2:H1222")
Dim Figs As Range             ' like figures
    Set Figs = Cells(1, 11)   
Dim cFreq As Range
    Set cFreq = Cells(2, 11)     
Dim cDev As Range              
    Set cDev = Cells(3, 11)
'Dim nums As Byte                  
     nums = 10                   'InputBox("blabla", "x")
Dim occData As Range
    Set occData = cFreq.Resize(1, nums)     ' occurrencies  
Dim MaxOccur As Long
    MaxOccur = cFreq.Offset(0, nums + 2).Value     '
Dim MinOccur As Long
    MinOccur = cFreq.Offset(0, nums + 3).Value
Dim LookupCellMax As Range                                  
    Set LookupCellMax = cFreq.Offset(0, nums + 2)
 '   MsgBox "LookupCellMax= " & LookupCellMax.Address & vbCrLf & LookupCellMax.Value
Dim LookupCellMin As Range
    Set LookupCellMin = cFreq.Offset(0, nums + 3)
  '  MsgBox "LookupCellMin= " & LookupCellMin.Address
Dim LookupVector As Range' 
    Set LookupVector = Range(Cells(1, 11), Cells(1, 11).Offset(1, nums - 1))
    ' MsgBox "LookupVector:  " & LookupVector.Address
Dim ResultVector As Long
    Set ResultVector =1            'Figs.Resize(1, nums)
           
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For szam = 1 To nums
        cFreq.Offset(0, szam - 1) = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(tart, szam)
                            
    Next szam

cFreq.Offset(0, nums + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Average(occData)    
cFreq.Offset(0, nums + 2) = WorksheetFunction.Max(occData)      
cFreq.Offset(0, nums + 3) = WorksheetFunction.Min(occData)      
 
   ' THE PROBLEMATIC SCRIPT STARTS HERE :

cFreq.Offset(2, nums + 6).Value = WorksheetFunction.HLookup(LookupCellMax.Value, LookupVector, ResultVector)       
     
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: HLookup is expecting 3 arguments with an optional 4th. `Lookup_value` as a number or string, `Table_array` as a range, and `Row_index_num` as a number. Your third argument `ResultVector` is a range when it should be a number. If you meant to use that formula as an array formula you need to use `.FormulaArray = ...` instead of `.Value = ...`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I've now altered the script above accordingly: The declaration of ResultVector is type Long, and assigned a numeric value to it.( = top row of the table).  Though the code terminated technically correctly, the product still remains faulty, as described in the initial summary. I'm not sure if I can interprete your last sentence precisely. In this case I did not declare an array. Would that help me ?

Comment: If this were my project, I'd do `Set rFind = TableRange.Find(What:=Worksheetfunction.Max(TableRange.Value), LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)` where `TableRange` is the worksheet range containing your data. And then to get other values in the same column you can do `rFind.EntireColumn.Cells(x)` where `x` is the row number of the cell you want.